# How to get SVN branching on completly different directories (not sub dirs)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository

Related to:

[How to setup the ideal collaboration repository setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994392/how-to-setup-the-ideal-collaboration-repository-setup)

I have the following setup on our develompent server:

```
[repos]
- [site repo]

[dev envs]
- [env a] (checkout of site repo)
- [env b] (checkout of site repo)
- [env c]
- [env d]
```

How can I get env c and d to be the location of the branches for env a?

Using subversions + TortoiseSVN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to read this chapter first: [4. Branching and Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html)

Briefly, you'll need to [create a branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create) from a trunk:

```
$ svn cp ^/repos/trunk ^/repos/branch/featureA
```

Then [checkout it](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.initial.html) wherever you want as working copy:

```
$ svn co ^/repos/branch/featureA featureA
```

When work is finished [reintegrate it back](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.reintegrate) to the trunk:

```
trunk_working_copy $ svn merge --reintegrate ^/repos/branch/featureA .
```