# Branching and Merging to a modified checkout

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn, repository

Hi have a repository checkout (SVN) which has been heavily modified by a team member. We would now like to get more than 1 member on the development to speed it up. In order to prevent any overwrites, It would be ideal if they could both work on seperate copies of this modified checkout and then merge their changes together.

Is there a way to do this in Subversion/TortoiseSVN? If not, is it an easy of a setup in git?

Related to:

[How to setup the ideal collaboration repository setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994392/how-to-setup-the-ideal-collaboration-repository-setup)

Comment: Can you describe that problem in more detail? *Any* version control system is precisely for the purpose of letting several people collaborate (among other things). What special case do you have that's not covered by the default behavior? Maybe you should read http://svnbook.red-bean.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TortoiseSVN

1. context menu click on Branch/Tag
2. In dialog box select "working copy" option in "Create copy in the repository from"

This will create a new branch from  modified checkout.Both the team members can check out this branch and can work simultaneously. When they are done with feature, they can merge their changes back to original repository.

Look at [this online help](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In `svn`, I would probably create a branch, check all those changes into it, and let the developers collaborate on that branch, committing changes as they see fit.

Once they are done, all changes (or just some of them) can be reintegrated into the upstream.